# Django rest framework user specific

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm confused about one part of how DRF works, I'm using django-rest-auth to register users. I would after that like them to each get a field in the models below, so that when they have picked fruit they can update their field and no one elses however I'm not really sure how I am suppost to link the django-rest-auth table with the other two and how I check which user it is that is updating their table

```
class fruits(models.Model):
   apples = models.IntegerField()
   bananas = models.IntegerField()
   oranges = models.IntegerField()

class berries(models.Model):
   strawberries = models.IntegerField()
   blackberries = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a `user` field in your model, so the user can get back to its own row.

```
class fruits(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

When you save the row you also save the specific user. When they want to update the same row again you just get the objects with

```
fruits.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: And how would I send the user data beside the user specific data? Should i add fields for that since my modelserializer doesnt or should that be done in the background somehow?

Comment: You could probably get the user data in the save-function in either the view or the form depending on how you render your form, instead of letting the client set it. I'd recommend you to go through the [Writing your first Django App](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) to get the basics on models, forms and views. I could answer questions on how to do things but it won't help if you don't understand what it does :)